# xml-conduit - combining tagParsers

Tags: haskell, xml-conduit

I have been trying to parse an XML-datastructure with xml-conduit, which seems to work after a bit of learning. But what I am now stuck on is the following.

Given a list of tag-parsers how do I use `choose` to combine them

```
data SumType = A Text | B Text | C Text

parseSumTypeList :: MonadThrow m => ConduitM Event o m (Maybe SumType)
parseSumTypeList = choose $ 
                   [ (tagIgnoreAttrs "A"
                     $ do result <- content
                          return (A $ result))
                   , (tagIgnoreAttrs "B"
                     $ do result <- content
                          return (A $ result))
                   , (tagIgnoreAttrs "C"
                     $ do result <- content
                          return (A $ result))]
```

While the above works fine - if I refactor the common pattern to

```
parseSumTypeList :: MonadThrow m => ConduitM Event o m (Maybe SumType)
parseSumTypeList = choose $ map f [("A",A),("B",B),("C",C)]
                 where f (str,constr) = tagIgnoreAttrs str
                                      $ do result <- content
                                           return (constr $ result)
```

I get the following error

```
Couldn't match type ‘ConduitM Event o0 m0 (Maybe SumType)’
               with ‘forall o1. ConduitM Event o1 m (Maybe SumType)’
Expected type: (Name, Text -> SumType)
               -> Consumer Event m (Maybe SumType)
  Actual type: (Name, Text -> SumType)
               -> ConduitM Event o0 m0 (Maybe SumType)
Relevant bindings include
  parseSumType :: Consumer Event m (Maybe SumType)
    (bound at ...)
In the first argument of ‘map’, namely ‘f’
In the first argument of ‘choose’, namely
  ‘(map f [("A", A), ("B", B), ("C", C)])’
```

It seems to me that the `forall o` part gets specialized - and therefore it is not a `forall` anymore, but that is just a guess.

from the documentation of `xml-conduit`

```
choose :: Monad m    
        => [Consumer Event m (Maybe a)] -- List of parsers that will be tried in order.
        -> Consumer Event m (Maybe a) -- Result of the first parser to succeed, or Nothing if no parser succeeded
```

and knowing that Consumer is just a type synonym

```
type Consumer i m r = forall o. ConduitM i o m r
```

### EDIT:

I tried with `f` as a lambda function - which also did not work.

```
parseSumTypeList = choose $ flip map [("A",A),("B",B),("C",C)]
                                     $\(str,constr) -> tagIgnoreAttrs str
                                        $ do result <- content
                                             return (constr $ result)
```

### EDIT2:

`ConduitErr.hs`

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
{-# LANGUAGE Rank2Types #-}

module ConduitErr where

import           Control.Monad.Trans.Resource (MonadThrow)
import           Text.XML.Stream.Parse
import           Data.Text (Text)
import           Data.XML.Types (Event)
import           Data.Conduit (ConduitM)
-- import           Control.Lens ((&),(.~))

data SumType = A Text | B Text | C Text

parseSumTypeList :: MonadThrow m => ConduitM Event o m (Maybe SumType)
parseSumTypeList = choose $
                   [ (tagIgnoreAttrs "A"
                        $ do result <- content
                             return (A $ result))
                   , (tagIgnoreAttrs "B"
                        $ do result <- content
                             return (B $ result))
                   , (tagIgnoreAttrs "C"
                        $ do result <- content
                             return (C $ result))]

parseSumTypeList' :: MonadThrow m => ConduitM Event o m (Maybe SumType)
parseSumTypeList' = choose $ map f [("A",A),("B",B),("C",C)]
                 where f (str,constr) = tagIgnoreAttrs str
                                      $ do result <- content
                                           return (constr $ result)
```

`foo.cabal`

```
[...]
  build-depends:       base >=4.8 && <4.9
               ,       conduit
               ,       resourcet
               ,       text
               ,       xml-conduit
               ,       xml-types
[...]
```

Comment: It would help out a lot if you list your imports.

Comment: The choose function has an impredictive type. Actually using impredictive types requires type signatures everywhere (where *exactly*? who knows...) because type inference cannot assign a polymorphic type. Since impredictive types are so difficult to use, I think this is just a design error on the parts of the library authors. The average user can't reasonably be expected to know all this if they just want to parse xml. A random guess is that putting a type signature on the function `f :: ... -> Consumer ....` and on the resultant list from map `(map ff [..] :: [Consumer ...])` might help.

Comment: Oh, and you may have to turn on `-XImpredictiveTypes` in your module.

Comment: @ErikR - did add a minimal failing example

Comment: @user2407038 I think I have to read some info about `ImpredictiveTypes` would you like to explain  a bit why the inference is not possible?

Comment: @epsilonhalbe If you would really like to know *why*, you probably need to read [this](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/simonpj/papers/boxy/boxy-icfp.pdf) paper, which details the part of the typechecker algorithm that ghc for `ImpredictiveTypes`.

Comment: @user2407038 then I'll have to first get into type theory - at least the notation is a bit strange for me, as I have not studied cs but math. So many unknown, but terribly interesting things. But thanks for the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `map`, but you can do this:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

import Control.Monad.Trans.Resource
import Data.Conduit
import Data.Text (Text, unpack)
import Data.XML.Types
import Text.XML.Stream.Parse

data SumType = A Text | B Text | C Text

parseList :: MonadThrow m => ConduitM Event o m (Maybe SumType)
parseList = choose [ mkCond "A" A , mkCond "B" B , mkCond "C" C ]
  where
    mkCond x xc = tagIgnoreAttrs x (content >>= (return . xc))
```

Comment: you see my mouth gaping in awe - ahem - why does your example work, and the map not ? how did you see this from the error message?